Sorting Variants by Throughput Time in a Simulated Production Line for Optimization Purposes in AnyLogic
I have created a population of agents called variants. I created this population with data from an Excel spreadsheet. Among other things, it contains the different variant numbers and the corresponding total processing times.
My goal is to model a production line, which I will later optimize based on the lead times. The production line consists of 5 stations and each variant takes a different amount of time at each station. As the next step in my modeling, I would like to sort the variants according to their total throughput time. However, this didn't quite work out. I have attached a screenshot showing my code. With this code it was possible to display the unsorted values but it does not work for the sorted ones. Can anyone help me with this?
 System.out.println("Varaints:" + variants.toString());
    // returns the population of angets unsorted
    
    List sortedByTotalTimeAsc  = sortAscending( variants, v -> v.gesamt);
    
    System.out.println("sortedByTotalTimeAsc:" + sortedByTotalTimeAsc.toString());
    // returns the list sorted as expected
    
    System.out.println("sortedByTotalTimeAsc imte 0 equals Varaints item 10 " + sortedByTotalTimeAsc.get(0).equals(variants.get(10)));
    // returns true (both list and population contain the same object)
    
    // Throws error besides same content as varaints as proven above
    //java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    sortedByTotalTimeAsc.forEach( variantElement -> {
            enterKlemmenleiste.take(variantElement);
            return;
    });
    
    // Does not throw error
    variants.forEach( variantElement -> {
            enterKlemmenleiste.take(variantElement);
            return;
    });


pls only use the "anylogic" tag, else you confuse other SOF users, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

You can use a Queue object and sort your agents by "priority", using whatever agent property you like.
Else, pre-sort your data via java comparators and create your agents in the sequence computed.
Else, pre-sort in your data.
Else, sort manually in a Wait block.
Else... (You see, there are tons of ways, it all depends on the specifics)

Hello Benjamin,
I will try it. Thank you for the respond!

sure. But pls improve your questions: Make them highly specific. If you want open-ended "how do I do X?", pls use the LinkedIn forum, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community

Sorry, its my first time using stackflow.
I added now my code

no worries, it is confusing the first time, read this to understand this place a bit more: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
